# Symfony + sonata + translation : You have requested a non-existent parameter "locale"

Tags: symfony, locale, sonata-admin

New to symfony i installed Sonata `composer require sonata-project/admin-bundle` and translator service `composer require symfony/translation`

As desciribed on symfony manual ([manual](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/getting_started/installation.html))
I added

```
    # config/packages/framework.yaml

framework:
    translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
```

but when I make a `php bin/console cache:clear` i get the error

*In ParameterBag.php line 100:

You have requested a non-existent parameter "locale".*

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to solve add in services.yaml:

```
parameters:
    locale: 'en' (en -> english, it -> italian ecc..)
```

and in framework.yaml

```
framework:
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    translator:
        fallbacks:
            - '%locale%'
```